# javascript - join 2 array of date

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, momentjs

I have a problem with `DateTime` in Javascript. My issue is that I have 2 array of `DateTime` range. For example:

```
var list1 = [
    {start: 2018-08-28 00:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 04:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 04:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 10:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 12:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 14:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 20:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 22:00:00},
];

var list2 = [
    {start: 2018-08-28 03:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 06:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 11:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 11:30:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 13:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 17:00:00},
];
```

After merge two list the result will be:

```
result = [
    {start: 2018-08-28 00:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 03:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 03:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 04:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 04:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 06:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 06:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 10:00:00},

    {start: 2018-08-28 11:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 11:30:00},

    {start: 2018-08-28 12:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 13:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 13:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 14:00:00},
    {start: 2018-08-28 14:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 17:00:00},

    {start: 2018-08-28 20:00:00, end: 2018-08-28 22:00:00},
];
```

## UPDATE:

This is a combination problem, not a sorting problem. For example: from 1:00 - 3:00 combine with 2:00 - 5:00 the result will be: [1:00 - 2:00, 2:00 - 3:00, 3:00 - 5:00].

If you have any idea please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey, I have a similar issue. Did you find the solution for this?. If yes can you post the solution.

Comment: @n1th1l: I write a code by myself, there is no library supporting it. Hope me answer can help you somehow

Comment: hey will it be possible to mention that answer here

Comment: @n1th1l: It is a private code, so I am not able to past it here

Comment: no worries, my problem statement changed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.concat to combine two arrays and then a custom comparator to sort them appropriately.

```
const output = list1.concat(list2).sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The thing is that this is not a sorting issue. I try to combine 2 array with DateTime inside. You can have a closer look at the result to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

It is now advisable to use ES6 syntax for joining the 2 arrays: Example below

```
result = [...list1, ...list2];
result.sort(function(a,b){
 // Turn your strings into dates and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.start) - new Date(a.start);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The thing is that this is not a sorting issue. I try to combine 2 array with DateTime inside. You can have a closer look at the result to see it :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you have a **date**, not a **number** or a **string**, that's why sorting will not work. You could make strings your dates:

```js
var list1 = [
    {start: "2018-08-28 00:00:00", end: "2018-08-28 04:00:00"},
    {start: "2018-08-28 04:00:00", end: "2018-08-28 10:00:00"},
    {start: "2018-08-28 12:00:00", end: "2018-08-28 14:00:00"},
    {start: "2018-08-28 20:00:00", end: "2018-08-28 22:00:00"},
];

var list2 = [
    {start: "2018-08-28 03:00:00", end: "2018-08-28 06:00:00"},
    {start: "2018-08-28 11:00:00", end: "2018-08-28 11:30:00"},
    {start: "2018-08-28 13:00:00", end: "2018-08-28 17:00:00"},
];

var result = list1.concat(list2).sort((a, b) => new Date(a.start) - new Date(b.start));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The thing is that this is not a sorting issue. I try to combine 2 array with DateTime inside. You can have a closer look at the result to see it :)